# How to pass Arraylist string to another class's adapter?

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, hashmap, adapter

i will like to pass pictureActivity.java array to another class imageAdapter.java.
I do get the imgPath result on toast, but i have no idea how to move the string to another class.

PictureActivity.java

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> imgList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    try {
        imageLink = json.getJSONArray(TAG_IMG);

        for(int i = 0; i < imageLink.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = imageLink.getJSONObject(i);
            String imgPath = c.getString(TAG_PATH);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(TAG_PATH, imgPath);

            imgList.add(map);
            Toast.makeText(this, map.get(TAG_PATH), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery))
            .setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context myContext;
    public String[] myRemoteImages = {
            //How to add imagepath here??
    };
```

I wanted to put the array string on myRemoteImages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass your array adapter while you initialize the adapter class object:

```
((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery))
            .setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, imgList));
```

and in your adapter class create a constructor like this:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = null;
  public String[] myRemoteImages;
  private Context myContext;

  public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data){
   this.mContext = context;
   this.data = data;

   myRemoteImages = new String[this.data.size()];
   for(int i=0; i<this.data.size(); i++){
     HashMap<String, String> map = this.data.get(i);
     myRemoteImages[i] = map.get(TAG_PATH).toString();
   }

  }
}
```

after getting the ArrayList in your adapter class, you may fetch whatever value you want out from it.

Comment: Hi Waqas, i am still relatively new to Java and Android.
How do i play with "data", to get the value? Can u show me the code?
I tried few way but i still can't figure it out.
e.g.
`public String[] myRemoteImages = {data.toString()};`
Thanks

Comment: i've updated the answer. now it shows how you can create an array of paths

Comment: Thanks very much Waqas!!
Btw imgList.size() & imgList.get(i) the imgList cannot be resolved.
I am using data.size() & data.get(i) instead.
Is ok right?

Comment: ohh yeah, sorry, my mistake. I looked at your code to update my answer. I've fixed it in my answer now :)